# MeteorJS javascript function defined in package is undefined

Tags: javascript, meteor, package, meteor-blaze

I have created a custom package in Meteor adding javascript to the application.

My `package.js`:

```
Package.describe({
    name: 'markel:theme',
    version: '1.0.0',
    summary: 'Theme package',
});

Package.onUse(function(api) {
    // Import all JS files required by the template

    api.addFiles(['assets/js/custom.js']);
});
```

In `custom.js`:

```
function theme_test() {
    console.log('Theme test');
}
```

When meteor loads the package in the application, it places the function in [IIFE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression). So the javascript is in `(function(){here})`. So my function will return undefined.

How can I define that function and use it?

Comment: Do you intend to import it? Please describe what you intend to do with it.

Comment: @Jankapunkt I want to use the functions I define in custom.js. So if I call theme_test() in a template helper it logs 'Theme test' to the console.

Comment: But the code neither shows, whether it is exported or added to global scope. The IIFE part in your example is hard to grasp. Can you may extend the code so it can be easily reproduce?

Comment: @Jankapunkt if you know how to install a local package, this is everything you need to reproduce it.

Comment: What I mean is, how do you make `theme_test` available to your project? Usually you either use `export` or add it to `global`, in this example it is just in scope of `custom.js` there is no way to use it outside of this module.

Comment: @Jankapunkt if you use `api.addFiles()` it exports the js and loads it in your application if you have your custom package installed.

Comment: @Jankapunkt I have made a public github repository that reproduces it. If you run the app you can see my custom js is loaded (localhost:3000/packages/marcelweidum_theme.js).

https://github.com/MarcelWeidum/stack-question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope one of these options will solve your issue, as I found it hard to reproduce any `undefined` values.

### Option 1 - Use modules

While you can auto-add files via `api.addFiles` you can optionally still export them explicitly:

*package.js*

```js
Package.describe({
    summary: 'Theming',
    version: '1.0.0',
    name: 'marcelweidum:theme',
    git: 'https://github.com/MarcelWeidum/stack-question.git'
});

Package.onUse((api) => {
    api.use('ecmascript') // required to use import/export
    api.addFiles([
        'js/custom.js'
    ], 'client');
    api.mainModule('main.js')
});
```

*package/js/custom.js*

```
export const theme_test = function theme_test () {
    console.log('Here am I!');
}

console.log('Loaded');
```

*package/main.js* (in root folder of the package)

```js
export { theme_test } from './js/custom'
```

*client/main.js*

```js
import { theme_test } from 'meteor/marcelweidum:theme'
theme_test()
```

will give you on the console:

```
Loaded
Here am I!
```

### Option 2 - use `api.export`

You can export the theme using an implicit global that is made accessible immediately using `api.export`:

*package.js*
Package.describe({
    summary: 'Theming',
    version: '1.0.0',
    name: 'marcelweidum:theme',
    git: 'https://github.com/MarcelWeidum/stack-question.git'
});

Package.onUse((api) => {
    api.addFiles([
        'js/custom.js'
    ], 'client');
    api.export('MyTheme')
});

```
*package/js/custom.js*
```

function theme_test () {
    console.log('Here am I!');
}

MyTheme = MyTheme || {}
MyTheme.theme_test = theme_test

console.log('Loaded');

````
*client/main.js*
```javascript
MyTheme.theme_test()
````

will give you on the console:

```
Loaded
Here am I!
```

### Option 3 - Import file explicitly

This will hover load the file's content only at the point it's imported

*package.js*
Package.describe({
  summary: 'Theming',
  version: '1.0.0',
  name: 'marcelweidum:theme',
  git: 'https://github.com/MarcelWeidum/stack-question.git'
})

Package.onUse((api) => {
  api.use('ecmascript')
})

````
*js/custom.js* (in root folder of the package)
```javascript
export const theme_test = function theme_test () {
    console.log('Here am I!');
}

console.log('Loaded');
````

*package/js/custom.js*

```
export const theme_test = function theme_test () {
    console.log('Here am I!');
}

console.log('Loaded');
```

*client/main.js*

```js
import { theme_test } from 'meteor/marcelweidum:theme/js/custom'
theme_test()
```

will give you on the console:

```
Loaded
Here am I!
```

### Option 4 use `bare` option, in case the file is used by a compiler plugin:

If you don't want the file to be wrapped inside a closure, for example because it will be used by a custom compier plugin, then add the `bare` option:

```js
Package.describe({
    summary: 'Theming',
    version: '1.0.0',
    name: 'marcelweidum:theme',
    git: 'https://github.com/MarcelWeidum/stack-question.git'
});

Package.onUse((api) => {
    api.addFiles([
        'js/custom.js'
    ], 'client',  { bare: true });
});
```

This will still load the file but you will have to use your isobuild plugin to handle the file.

Comment: Only option 1 is working, but to do that for every function is not doable. For example: if I want to load bootstrap.js in my package, I can't make for .tooltip() an export and every other function. I know there is already a package for bootstrap but it is just an example.

Comment: If you want the Bootstrap tooltoip class you can use option 3: `import { Tooltip }  from 'bootstrap/js/src'` which imports the `class Tooltip` for you.